# Security of using AND instead of XOR operation for an OTP

Tags: encryption, one-time-pad

With One-Time-Pads I have heard that it is preferential to use XOR because the ciphertext reveals no information about what the plaintext may have been (for each `0` and `1` of the ciphertext there is a 50% chance that the plaintext was a `0` or a `1`).

In contrast AND means that some information is revealed about the plaintext from the ciphertext (for each `1` in the ciphertext you can be sure there was a `1` in the plaintext). However, my question is if there is enough information revealed to genuinely be a security risk? For instance, take the following ciphertext:

```
c = 000100100011000010010000
```

Using this ciphertext an attacker could begin to predict some characteristics of the plaintext.

```
p = xxx1xx1xxx11xxxx1xx1xxxx
```

On average an attacker would be able to predict 25% of the plaintext immediately from observing the ciphertext. They also know that on average a third of the remaining plaintext is `1`, and that the other two-thirds are `0` though they do not have any clues to begin to predict which are which from my knowledge.

Is there any attack that could be performed given the knowledge that each remaining bit has a 2/3 chance to be a `0`? Perhaps an algorithm that would reduce the number of operations needed to predict the entirety of the plaintext? I would assume intuitively, but cannot quite conceptualise the maths involved, that on average you would only need to guess 1/3 of the remaining bits till you found the correct plaintext. Hence, a 256-bit size ciphertext would only need `2^64` 'brute-force' attempts before on average the correct plaintext was found.

Is there any attack that could be performed given the knowledge of on average 25% of the plaintext immediately, and each `1` in the plaintext? I would have assumed that there weren't any attacks that could be performed given this knowledge. Though if most of ciphertext was `1` then this might begin to significantly reduce the number of 'brute-force' attempts needed.

Comment: _"it is preferential to use XOR"_ Actually no. That's just from computation and doesn't really work with pen and paper.. Any bijective mapping works for OTP's with 100% informational secrecy.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It really doesn't matter. The problem is not so much that the plaintext can be guessed, the problem is that if the bit in the key stream is zero, then the result of the AND will always be zero as well:

Here is the table for AND at a certain index:

| Key | Plaintext | Ciphertext |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |

As such, the decrypt is not possible as the operation is not reversible. If the ciphertext is zero and the key is zero then the plaintext is 0 or 1 with a chance of 50% exactly, i.e. in that case the information loss for that particular bit is complete. In other words, a zero key bit will fully erase the information contained by the plaintext bit.

---

Now say that this is not a problem and we're only interested in the security, not the loss of information about the plaintext (uh, yeah).

In that case we still have a problem: if the ciphertext bit is one then we know with probability 1 that the plaintext was also 1. And if the ciphertext is zero then there is a $2 \over 3$ chance that the plaintext was zero as well - assuming a normal distribution of plaintext bits.

There is no more information to be found from the ciphertext, as the bits in the key stream are correctly distributed and independent. However, if there is more information about the plaintext then we can guess with higher probability. Say that you use Java and a boolean is set to a byte with value `00000000` for false or `11111111` for true. Now if just *one of the bits in the ciphertext* is set to 1 then an adversary knows that the boolean must be true, and if it is set to all zero then there is a 255 out of 256 chance that the boolean is false (and a remaining 1 out of 256 chance that the boolean is true). The issue is here that the plaintext bits *are dependent* on each other.

So your answer is that no, we don't have more information **unless** we can derive if from knowledge about the plaintext.

---

There is one other operation on two bits that would work similar to XOR: XNOR, which is simply the inverse of XOR:

| Key | Plaintext | Ciphertext |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |

And it is possible to have carry-less addition / subtraction over a group other than 2. For instance over a byte (8 bits) you can perform addition $k + p + x = c \mod 2^8$ where $x$ is a constant, usually zero.

Comment: That XNOR looks surprisingy similar to k == p

Comment: It's not asked, but I'm struggling a bit to give a formal definition of the properties of a function so that it represents a one time pad. Sure, a bijective function, but that doesn't give any hints on what the key should be.

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe With individual bits, it _is_ k == p, and normal XOR is k != p.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes: You want that the operation * mapping a message m and a key k to a ciphertext c = m * k is a quasigroup operation. This ensures that for every message and every ciphertext, there is a unique key that would encrypt the message to the given ciphertext (this gives security), and similarly, there is a unique message for every key and ciphertext (ensuring correctness).

Comment: So I am gathering this would mean that out of all the possible bitwise operators, only XOR and XNOR abide by these rules @ChristianMatt? OR, AND, and their derivatives seem to fail these requirements. I also notice that XOR and XNOR are the only bitwise operations that do not distribute over any other operations - is there a relation between these two observations?

Comment: @ChristianMatt: actually, it can be made a bit more general than that; what is needed is that for every possible $P, C$ combination, there is the same number of keys $K$ for which $C = E(K, P)$.  This number can be one (which gives you a 'quasigroup operation' (actually, a latin square); however it can also be more than one...

Comment: @poncho: That indeed is enough for security. If you also want to be able to decrypt, you additionally need that for every K and C, there is a unique P.

Comment: @ChristianMatt: oops; I had assumed that invertibility was implied by the criteria I gave - I now see that it is not.  Thanks for the correction

Answer (score 1):

Here's an image where I combined the pixel data with a string of random bytes using AND:

[image: Tux the penguin combined with random bytes using AND]
<sub>Attribution: lewing@isc.tamu.edu Larry Ewing and The GIMP</sub>

You don't have to brute-force all of the unknown bits to figure out what that is. For comparison, here's the same thing but with XOR:

[image: Tux the penguin combined with random bytes using XOR]

Comment: Is there an example of using the above picture with XOR? While I imagine it would be harder I doubt most people would not be able to roughly guess what the picture is still in this case. By using AND you do have the trouble of (in regards to an image) all the black pixels remaining black.

Comment: @James See the edit. With XOR, the result is indistinguishable from random data to someone without the key and zero information about the plaintext other than its length is revealed.

Comment: Can you explain how have you obtain these images? I've tried with GMIC bitwise operators and GraphicsMagick -operator option but I don't get the same. Thanks!!